# How to remove the lines that are being generated beneath my bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I was wondering how to remove the lines beneath the nav-bars located on my page. I am using the basic twitter bootstrap navbar.

Here is a link to screenshot pointing to the lines I am talking about.

[image]

Edit2:Here is a bootply link containing the HTML and CSS for my apllication. The background image is not on the bootply, but I do not believe that should interfere with the solution. : http://www.bootply.com/7lzRzgs0YF

Edit3: Here is a working solution provided by @Raptus. I changed the nav-tabs css class to include a border of 0px instead of 1px.

```
.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li {
float:none;
display:inline-block;
font:17px fantasy;
border:0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;   
}
.navbar-brand{
font:bold 25px century gothic;
}
.nav-tabs {
text-align:center;
border:0px;
}
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;    
}
#content{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 55%;
height: 83%;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
html, body{
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-image: url('../content/Technology_016.jpg');
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#foot{
height: 9.25%;
}
#nav1{
height: 9.25%;
}
```

Comment: show us the relevant css and HTML code

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please share your relevant code so we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Could you please provide a JSFiddle of your work, pasteBin isn't too great as it doesn't give you live results of any changes to that code.

Comment: @Raptus bootply.com is here too for boostrap stuff...

Comment: @TheLittlePig Indeed though I wasn't intending to give a list of available code publishers.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone for the help so far. I have uploaded the code into bootply.com and put the link in the edit. You guys are awesome and I am sorry to inconvenience you all.

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer! :P

Comment: @Raptus your solution has worked properly. Thank you all so much for your time you guys are awesome, --Fredrick Khoury

Comment: @Raptus I am not sure what you mean by tick the answer. Would you mind elaborating on how I might go about doing so?

Comment: @fredkorey just hover around the answer and a tick below the answer rating (The zero) should appear, and click that to mark as answered, useful for me, useful for letting people know that your question is answered.

Comment: @Raptus ok I think I got it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it for you my friend seems like your .nav-tabs class has a 1px border set for it, remove that and you should have no more problems.